# What should I substitute in this Integral?

Tags: integration, substitution, change-of-variable

I have to do homework and need help with this integral. We were supposed to use Fubinis theorem on it, which I think I did. Anyway this is the integral given to us: $$\int_0^1 \int_{x_1}^1 x_2^2 \cdot \sin\left(\frac{2\pi x_1}{x_2}\right)\, dx_2\, dx_1 $$

Which I changed to:$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{x_2}x_2^2 \cdot \sin\left(\frac{2\pi x_1}{x_2}\right) \,dx_1 \,dx_2$$

Now I've checked this integral on a few calculators and apparently, if it is correct, it's gigantic.
So I wanted to ask, if this is correct, what should I substitute to make it actually computable by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_{0}^{x_{2}}x_{2}^{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi x_{1}}{x_{2}}\right){\rm d}x_{1}=-\dfrac{x_{2}^{3}}{2\pi}\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi x_{1}}{x_{2}}\right)\Bigg|_{x_{1}=0}^{x_{1}=x_{2}}=-\dfrac{x_{2}^{3}}{2\pi}\left[\cos2\pi-\cos0\right]=0$$

Comment: Well, idiotically I forgot solving the first integral in its bounds. Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The integral is improper so the first step is invalid.

Comment: @B.Goddard To me it looks perfectly valid. For $x_{2}\neq0$ you don't have any problems, and for $x_{2}\rightarrow0$ the function approaches $0$ because of the $x_{2}^{2}$ on the outside. See here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%5E2*sin(2pi+x%2Fy)

Comment: When I do it in numerically Maple, and set the lower limit to various negative powers of 10, I get wildly varying answers.  $\sin(1/y)$ is a little crazy near $0$, so it's not clear to me that the the first step is legal.

Comment: @B.Goddard I added the $x_{2}^{2}$ from the original function (I initially ignored it since the inner integral is wrt $x_{1}$). Thanks for the correction. Now it should be properly defined since $x_{2}^{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi x_{1}}{x_{2}}\right)$ has merely a removable line of discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_2$ takes on the value $0$ in this domain, the integral is improper.  So you can't switch the order of integration like you have (without proving a Fubini theorem.)  You can integrate the original integral by parts twice and then take the limit.

(I'd write more buy my plumber just showed up...)